# Why is determinism expressed by the Chapman-Kolmogorov law and not by the mere existence of an evolution operator?

Tags: classical-mechanics, determinism

The following excerpt is from pages 60-61 of Abraham's *Foundations of Mechanics*:

[image]

[image]

---

The last remark is a bit confusing to me. I would have said that it is the existence of the evolution operator that implies determinism, as it shows that *the mere fact of being in state $s_1$ at time $t_1$ implies we will find ourselves in (a **determined**) state $s_2$ at time $t_2$*.

Why does the author claim instead that determinism is expressed by the Chapman-Kolmogorov law?